# How to join continuous number and float elements together from list and return a new one in a pretty way?

Tags: python

```
lst1 = ['d','5','.','7','7','.','d']
lst2 = ['5','.','7','a','7','.','d']
lst3 = ['5','.','7','a','7','.','d','d']
```

Try:

```
def zipNum(l):
    new_lst = []
    tmp = []
    for w in l:
        if w.isdigit() or w in ['.']:
            tmp.append(w)
        else:
            if tmp:
                new_lst.append(''.join(tmp))
                new_lst.append(w)
                tmp = []
            else:
                new_lst.append(w)
    if bool(new_lst)==False or tmp:
        new_lst.append(''.join(tmp))
    return new_lst
```

For example,

```
new_lst1 = zipNum(lst1)
new_lst2 = zipNum(lst2)
new_lst3 = zipNum(lst3)

new_lst1 = ['d', '5.77.', 'd']
new_lst2 = ['5.7', 'a', '7.', 'd']
new_lst2 = ['5.7', 'a', '7.', 'd','d']
```

Notice: Each element in raw list is string format. And element which isn't number or float would not join together.

Hope: a pretty way to get results.

Comment: And your expected output?

Comment: The `new_lst1` and `new_lst2`

Comment: What is your current code producing that is incorrect?

Comment: Not incorrect , but it want if there is a pretty way to get the result

Comment: If you're trying to prettify already-working code, then you'll get better results on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What should happen in the case of `['d','1','.','2','3','.','4']`? Should it be transformed to `['d','1.23.4']`? Or `['d','1.2','3.4']`? What are the rules?

Comment: @Piinthesky yes

Comment: How do you define "pretty"? You mean pythonic?

Comment: @Jack Erm..... Piinthesky gave two alternatives. "Yes" is not a response that makes sense.....

Comment: @cricket_007 I think the code is a bit long and it seems hard to understand for others at once.

Comment: Then add comments. Trying to write your code in fewer, complex lines, won't help anyone understand it either

Comment: @cricket_007 cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's answer is a good result.

Comment: @Piinthesky Sorry, the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code and output, it would seem like a simple grouping operation using `itertools.groupby` can be used. You can define a function to handle the grouping and concatenation -

```
from itertools import groupby

def merge_float_components(lst):
    r = []
    for i, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x.isdigit() or x == '.'):
        if i:
            r.append(''.join(list(g)))
        else:
            r.extend(list(g))

    return r
```

Now, call it, passing your lists as input -

```
>>> merge_float_components(['d', '5', '.', '7', '7', '.', 'd'])
['d', '5.77.', 'd']
```

```
>>> merge_float_components(['5','.','7','a','7','.','d'])
['5.7', 'a', '7.', 'd']
```

```
>>> merge_float_components(['5', '.', '7', 'a', '7', '.', 'd', 'd'])
['5.7', 'a', '7.', 'd', 'd']
```

---

You may want to *parse* these values as well. One option is to iterate, and use the EAFP approach when converting the string (using `try-except` clauses to catch and handle errors) -

```
def merge_float_components(lst):
    for i, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x.isdigit() or x == '.'):
        if i:
            v = ''.join(list(g))
            try:
               yield float(v.strip('.'))
            except ValueError:
               yield v
        else:
            yield from list(g)   # python3.3+
```

Now, calling this function will return a generator (because of `yield`), and you can wrap a `list` call around it to collect the results into a list -

```
>>> list(merge_float_components(['d', '5', '.', '7', '7', '.', 'd']))
['d', 5.77, 'd']
```

Notice that the element in the center is now a `float`.

You can also re-write this with the LYBL approach (using an `if` statement) -

```
import re

def merge_float_components(lst):
    for _i, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x.isdigit() or x == '.'):
        if _i:
            i = ''.join(list(g))
            j = i.strip('.')

            yield float(j) if re.match('\d+(?:\.\d+)?', j) else i
        else:
            yield from list(g)
```

`re.match` performs validation on the string, validating `float`s and `ints. This function produces the same result as before -

```
>>> list(merge_float_components(['d', '5', '.', '7', '7', '.', 'd']))
['d', 5.77, 'd']
```

Comment: I might suggest an `rstrip('.')`. Otherwise, nice solution

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have updated my question, your answer could not solve the third situation(new_lst3)

Comment: @Jack I fixed the function for you. If your question was resolved, please vote on, and accept the answer. Thanks.